# Git: renaming a directory deletes all files from git

Tags: git

I use Git for a project of mine. In one of the directory there are some files. Now I need to rename the directory. After I renamed the directory, `git status` shows all my files as deleted. So it means I have to add those files again as new file in Git. But I don't want to add all those files as new in Git again.

Is there any way, to rename the directory instead of adding the whole directory and files as new in Git?

Comment: No, I don't think there is a way to do this.  When you rename the folder, you also rename all the contents inside.  The best case scenario might be that Git would figure out that you are renaming, rather than deleting and adding, the files.

Comment: Git commits are snapshots not change-sets. There is no difference in rename vs. delete + add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git mv --dry-run oldDir newDir
```

Look good?

```
git mv oldDir newDir
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can simply try to `git add` your old now-deleted folder as well as the new one. Then run `git status` and you’ll see how `git` interpreted your changes. It will most likely show your changes as moves, not as deletions & additions.

Answer (score 0):

The renaming detection is done only when files are added to the `staging area` (also called `index`).

So, if you renamed the folder, you will see in your `git status`:

- all the files of the old folder as deleted
- all the files in the new folder as untracked

You have in fact 2 way to do this renaming:

- `git add` all the untracked files (and git will use its statistical algorithm to find, most of the time well, the files renaming)
- instead of renaming the folder yourself, use the git command to do it for you (`git mv`). That way, git will do the `add` for you and all we be well.

Answer (score 0):

just command : git mv olddirectory_name new_name